# How to NOT highlight the current date in JQueryMobile calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this `js` code :

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="visibility:hidden; height: 0px;">

            <input 
                name="mydate" 
                id="mydate" 
                pickPageTheme="a"
                data-role="datebox"
                data-options='{"mode": "calbox" }' />

            </div>
            <a href="#" id="linkmodelink" data-role="button">show</a>
```

how not to highlight the current date

Comment: I've had to do something similar on a standard web app - different lib though. It didn't have an option to "not" highlight the current date so I just found out what CSS style gave it the highlighted effect and changed it to do nothing. Does this help?

Comment: no nothing unique in the CSS for the element represents the current date

Answer (score 3):

There is a flag that lets you turn that off in the HTML options:

```
data-options='{"calHighToday": false}'
```

It turns it off and you don't have to modify any CSS or JS files.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I found it finally.

```
    pickPageTodayButtonTheme: 'e',
```

This is located in the js file, change it to the theme you want.

Comment: the second code only change the text of the current date and don't change the background color

Comment: you must edit this file http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css I'm looking for what to change now.

Comment: the theme used for current date will be used in other dates, so I can't change it !

Comment: today's date has the class btn-up-e or btn-down-e , I mean it has the theme e while the others have theme a, so it might be changed from the js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding this style as follows:

```
.ui-state-default.ui-state-highlight {
  background: blue;
}
```

This style seems to be unique to the current date.

You should see the current day will turn blue. You can then do whatever you need with it. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks you but i need the original theme '.ui-btn-up-e' as it is for other dates

Comment: I changed the class used in the example. That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

edit this first into a style that doesn't exist, for example "k"

`pickPageTodayButtonTheme: 'k'`,

then add the new style to the css, but don't forget you have to copy everything the other themes have, for example

```
.ui-btn-up-k {
  background: blue !important;
}
.ui-btn-down-k {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

and so on.